# How do "layer", "feature", "attribute", "field", and "data provider" relate?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, terminology

I'm new to QGIS, but familiar with Python and PyQt, and am trying to make sense of the terminology of "layer", "feature", "attribute", "field", and "data provider". Every time I think I understand what they represent and how they relate, the PyQgis API throws me for a loop.

Here's how I understand it.  A *layer* is a component of a map visualization, the 'view', so to speak, corresponding to the 'model' data given by a [*data provider*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762723/what-is-dataprovider-in-pyqgis-and-what-does-it-do). A *feature* is a thing of interest on the map. Information about a feature is stored in the data provider. Data is categorized as [either GIS or non-GIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/introducing_gis.html#gis-data). Non-GIS data is accessed by users as though it were stored in two dimensions via the *attribute* table. The [table consists of records (rows) and *fields* (columns)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_attribute_data.html#attributes-in-detail).   Features are provided by the provider and managed by a layer which is in turn handled by the canvas. We say that a record is an attribute and this corresponds to a feature.

[image: professional illustration of the relationships]

This mental model feels cohesive until I do something like try to define several  features in a vector layer. In that case, I need to do things like get the provider from the layer and specify feature fields through an API call named "setAttribute".

```py
layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer("point", "points", "memory")

provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([qgis.core.QgsField('uuid', QtCore.QVariant.String, 'str', 32)])
layer.updateFields()

for point in self.point_list:
    feature = qgis.core.QgsFeature()
    feature.setFields(layer.fields(), True)  # needed to reference by name
    feature.setAttribute('uuid', point['uuid'])
    geom = qgis.core.QgsGeometry.fromWkt(point['geom'])
    feature.setGeometry(geom)
    provider.addFeature(feature)

layer.renderer().symbol().setColor(QtGui.QColor("red"))
layer.updateExtents()
```

I would instead expect to be able to define a provider up-front and assign it to a layer.

I also would expect to put a value in a column with something like "setColumn" or "setField" since a feature is an attribute, right?

I also notice that many objects have similar methods. For example, layers can delete attributes.  I thought attributes were just for data providers and features.

Are those just for convenience or is data stored there outside the data provider?

Comment: usually, `feature`s are rows and `attribute`s are columns or fields on a `feature`

Comment: A layer has more than just pointing to the features (rows of geometries+attributes), as it can also contain styling information, labeling instruction, metadata, projection information etc. It is however a very convenient abstraction of the underlying data provider functions: `feature.setAttribute('field_name', value)` can be used regardless of the data storage, could it be in a database, in a file or even just in memory.